# Why does next/image generate inline styling that resets my css?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I’m intending to use next/image to optimize the images on my site. However, after building the project, all of my images are getting a style attribute with what seems to be reset styling.
I’m new to React and Next.js and I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem.

**This is my next/image:**

```
<Image src="/images/KontacktPhoto.jpg"
    loading="lazy"
    id="w-node-c2896189-6d63-ce1c-bac3-f0aee0dcc9c2-e0dcc9be"
    alt
    className="image-4"
    layout="fill"
/>
```

**and this is the image that is rendered in the browser:**

```
<img id=”myPic” src="/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75" decoding="async" class="image-4" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%" sizes="100vw" srcset="/_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=640&amp;q=75 640w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=750&amp;q=75 750w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=828&amp;q=75 828w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=1080&amp;q=75 1080w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=1200&amp;q=75 1200w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=1920&amp;q=75 1920w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=2048&amp;q=75 2048w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimages%2FKontacktPhoto.jpg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75 3840w">
```

**As you can see next/image has added this style attribute to the image:**

```
style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%"
```

I understand that this may be a feature of next/image to make the built in 'layout' property work properly. However if I manually remove the style attribute in the browser, the image seems to be displaying correctly.

Is there any way to let next/image know that I don’t want this style attribute?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a built-in way to do so - [`next/image` source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/client/image.tsx#L341). What styling are you trying to apply to the image? Have you tried adding a wrapper `div` and styling that instead?

Comment: Yes adding the styles to a div wrapper might work but what I don’t understand is why next/image is adding this styles override in the first place? The only problem I see with adding the styles to a wrapper instead is that all global styles that I have applied to the img tag itself will be ignored. 

The reason that this is an issue is because I am building a automated html to nextjs converter. If it was just for a single project this would not be an issue :/

Comment: Adding a div wrapper to override the image style will not work since your dealing with an inline style. Try to look at CSS specificity.